# Azure b2c block sign in on sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, claims

Is it possible to have a user profile have "block sign in" set to true on account sign up? The goal that I'm going for is to essentially have an account need to be approved before they can sign in

I've tried messing with the custom policy starter pack and in the "AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" technical profile I added a PersistClaim for the accountEnabled claim

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            ...
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            ...
            
<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" DefaultValue="false" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            ...
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            ...
          </OutputClaims>
          
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: you should probably have a look at the invitation flow ?

Comment: @Thomas  Aren't invitation flows only for adding them as a member of the directory and not a local account (hopefully i'm using the terms correctly). Plus ideally I'd like people to still be able see the option to sign up and do so, just not be enabled. the invitation flow would require me to send them an invite

Comment: It s more about signin up only invited user so you dont allow user to create an account. How did you o with the `accountEnabled` claim ?